# GAS .rept does not receive a label?

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, gnu-assembler

In NASM, I can easily do it using label like this

```
times 510-($-$$) db 0
                 db 0x55, 0xaa
```

However, I can not use label in a GAS `.rept` command, It is invalid

```
current:
.rept 510-current-_start
.byte 0
.endr
; Error occures `Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression`
```

1. I wonder what is a absolute expression(I saw it in a gas document), I think `510-current-_start` should be accepcted because the value of this is calculated while compiling.
2. How can I elegantly put `0x55` and `0xaa` in a right position?
3. I found `.space` works but `.rept` doesn't, why?

```
; It works
current:
.space 510-current-_start

; Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
current:
.rept 510-current-_start
.byte 0
.endr
```

EDITED:

It does't work too(using parentheses), I think It might be a bug?

```
; Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
current:
.rept 510-(current-_start)
.byte 0
.endr
```

Comment: `.org 510` should work, Some options in the answers to this other SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859273/calculating-padding-length-with-gas-att-directives-for-a-boot-sector

Comment: You are right. `.org 510` works. And `.space 510-(.-_start)` also works.
But the code below doesn't work?
`.rept 510-(.-_start)\n
.byte 0\n
.endr`

Comment: @Markity: You don't really need the `.rept` with `gas`. If `.org` causes the file position to advance, the default action is to fill with `0`.

Comment: @Michael Petch Doesn't the boot loader need to be located at `0x7C00`? Or are `.org` directives relative in GAS, allowing you to say `.org 510` to evaluate to `.org 7E00h`?

Comment: @puppydrum64 : The `.org` directive doesn't work the same in GAS as it does in something like NASM. In GAS it is relative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085027/gas-org-different-from-org-in-nasm . With GAS you'd need to specify the origin point during the linking stage.

Comment: @MichaelPetch That's what I imagined. Also I made a typo in my earlier comment, I meant `.org 7DFE` at the end there.

Comment: @Markity Did you try using parentheses? As in, `.rept 510-(current-_start)`? Maybe the order of operations you used is resulting in a negative number which obviously doesn't make sense.

Comment: @puppydrum64 I tryied but still failed, maybe `.rept` only accepct a specific number. I should ignore this problem because I can use other methods.